# Need to find only exact matches in multivalued field

Tags: solr, field, string-matching

in my solr documents I use a multivalued field to store some colorIDs

(e.g. "10","130","190")

If in my query I search for colorID 30 (fq=colorID:30) I get documents which have the 30 as colorID, but additionally there are results which have only "130" as part of multivalued field. 
But I ONLY need to get those who exactly match to "30"

Is it possible to setup that field to get that exact results only? 
What FilterFactory do I have to use, Tokenizers etc...

Any help would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using built-in field types in Solr, you can accomplish exact matches using the "string" data type for the field. (You could use "int" as well, but if you're doing strict lookup type of queries, string will suffice.)

Post your schema definition from schema.xml to clarify.

Comment: `<field name="searchColor" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="searchColor_raw" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="searchColor_raw" dest="searchColor"/>` If I do the search by Using tie "_raw" field which is of type "string" I get the correct results. Thanks for that help!

Comment: Ok, sounds like that works, but your original query goes against "ColorID", which isn't defined here (could it be a dynamic field?) Additionally, you probably don't require "multiValued" on your fields, unless you consider those fields an array of information per document.

Comment: ah ...sorry...I mixed those fieldnames as writing my example here. I use "searchColor" in field definitions and in my query ;)

Comment: Hi Casper,  can you please tell me how are you searching. because i have defined like thisin the schema.xml     <field name="searchColor" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>   <field name="searchColor_raw" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> 
 <copyField source="searchColor_raw" dest="searchColor_raw"/>     when i search based on the searchColor_raw:"Test" OR searchColor_raw:"Test123" getting undefined error.can you pls help.